Copy file from USS into a PDS Member
I needed to copy a shell script (tagged ISO-8859-1) from my home directory into a PDS member where I am storing many of my shell scripts for easy sharing (one xmit of the pds works fine - someday I'll move to a pax file but for now).
I've tried without success, as the results are always ascii text in the PDS member, the following:

ISPF Edit PDS member and use the COPY command.

without checking ASCII or UTF-8 it came across as ASCII text
when checking ASCII or UTF-8 it was not usable as the lines were
split in strange locations


OGET just didn't work
cp ~/script /dsfs/txt/hlq/pds/script

results in CEE5239S The signal SIGDSIOER was received with a SYSLOG error message about the LRECL being longer than the dataset LRECL (which is 255), and an empty member




The only solution that worked was this convoluted process:

use ISPF 3.17 or UDList to view the directory where the script resides
Edit the script
Use the Edit COPY command to copy the entire contents into the ISPF Edit clipboard
exit 3.17/UDList
ISPF Edit the PDS member
Use the ISPF Edit PASTE command to paste the clipboard contents into the member

That works.

How does the file look like in USS? Does the data appear as a single line or does it have line breaks?  If the file has a single line, then you probably need to chop it up based on the line breaks.  If you have the proper line breaks then DFSORT can used to copy it from USS to a member of a PDS

it looks fine in USS with each individual line as expected using cat and less and vi/vim.

Lionel, did you try OGET with the CONVERT operand set as follows: CONVERT((BPXFX311))
Specifies an ASCII-EBCDIC conversion table to convert between code pages ISO8859-1 and IBM-1047.
Documented here : Single Byte Conversion

i tried but didn't work :(

And a little more reading tells us why: Quoting from the OGETX page, it only uses the FROM1047, never the TO1047 part: CONVERT(character_conversion_table | YES | NO)
Specifies that the data being copied is to be converted from code page 1047 to code page IBM-237 or ASCII. That is, the FROM1047 part of the specified character conversion table is used.

I have a mainframe account that has both USS files and Z/OS files, and was able to use OGETX to copy from my USS file directly into a Z/OS pds member without having to specify CONVERT, etc.
So, try using OGETX without any extra parameters, etc.

FWIW, I had a problem copying from uss to z/os PDS.  It turns out the problem was that I had the PDS member list open in ISPF.  Once I canceled out of the member list in ISPF, the copy worked.
$ /bin/cp foo "//'xxx.yyy.zzz'"

Now in ispf, I have a xxx.yyy.zzz(foo) file.
